# How does push forward work?

Tags: ground-operations

From Facebook video shows a BA aircraft being pushed forward into a hangar. I wonder how it works? Do they rotate nose wheel 180 degree to push it or there is attachment point for the tug to push forward?

[image: BA aircraft push forward into hangar]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it common for aircraft tugs to work from under the aircraft?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/75212/is-it-common-for-aircraft-tugs-to-work-from-under-the-aircraft)